# Insufficient Storage Space problem

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have 53 MB of free storage on my internal Storage. But, still, when I am trying to re-install whatsapp messenger, (which is merely of 17.53 MB) after uninstalling it initially, it shows Insufficient Storage Space. 
Specifications:
Model Number : Micromax A58,
Android Version : 4.2.2

What should I do to solve this memory problem?

Comment: The tag [tag:insufficient-memory] has related questions and some good answers. Have a look  and tell us if things worked out or not.

Comment: Short answer: Those 17.5 MB have to be downloaded from the store (get stored in `/data/local`), then the app has to be installed (installed size is larger; so say, conservatively, 20 MB added to that), and then the temporary file gets removed. While in the second step, that makes ~40 MB space needed, leaving less than 15 MB free --> the "insufficient memory" error gets triggered (less than 25 MB or less than 10% of storage). For more, follow the link @Firelord gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion 1:
(At your own risk)
Go to Settings > Apps. 
Select Google and Clear data. 
Select Maps and Clear data. 
Select Chrome and Clear data (only if you have logged in to Chrome and made sure that all your bookmarks are synced to Google Servers).

Suggestion 2:
(If memory is too low, try Suggestion 1 at your risk and then try this) 
Install the app *Clean Master* and Clean junk

Suggestion 3:
(At your own risk)
Root your phone (rooting can be risky and might essentially kill your phone if not done properly with full knowledge). 
Install Link2SD and move all apps to external SD card

Suggestion 4: 
(least risky) 
Go to Settings > Apps, select the 'Downloaded' tab and then select apps one by one and move them to external/USB card.